# JQuery UI: For Modal, want different animation if OK vs Cancel button is pushed

Tags: jquery

I'd like to Fade the dialog in but vary the animation depending on whether the OK or the Cancel button is pushed. If the OK button is pushed, I'd like to FadeOut, else Explode.

How can I modify my existing code to do this?

```
function confirmCancelReadyToRun(link, vendorId, runYearMonthDate, runYearMonthDisplay) {

    var $myDialog = $("<div></div>")
           .html("Are you sure that you want to Cancel the Ready to Run for Vendor ID " + vendorId + " on " + runYearMonthDisplay + "?")
           .dialog({
               modal: true,
               autoOpen: false,
               show: "fade",
               title: "Confirm Cancel",
               my: "center",
               at: "center",
               of: window,
               buttons: {
                   "Cancel": function () {
                       $(this).dialog("close");
                       return false;
                   },
                   "OK": function () {
                       $(this).dialog("close");
                       var form = $(link).parents("form:first");
                       var actionString = encodeURI(CorrectUrl("/ReadyToRun/CancelReadyToRun?vendorId=" + vendorId + "&runYearMonthDate=" + runYearMonthDate));
                       form.attr("action", actionString);
                       form[0].submit();
                       return true;
                   }
               }
           });

    $myDialog.dialog("open");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the option for `hide` just before you close the dialog (or at the point you know what effect you want):

```js
function confirmCancelReadyToRun(link, vendorId, runYearMonthDate, runYearMonthDisplay) {

  var $myDialog = $("<div></div>")
    .html("Are you sure that you want to Cancel the Ready to Run for Vendor ID " + vendorId + " on " + runYearMonthDisplay + "?")
    .dialog({
      modal: true,
      autoOpen: false,
      show: "fade",
      title: "Confirm Cancel",
      my: "center",
      at: "center",
      of: window,
      buttons: {
        "Cancel": function() {
          $(this).dialog("option", "hide", "explode");
          $(this).dialog("close");
          return false;
        },
        "OK": function() {

          $(this).dialog("option", "hide", "fade");
          $(this).dialog("close");

          //var form = $(link).parents("form:first");
          //var actionString = encodeURI(CorrectUrl("/ReadyToRun/CancelReadyToRun?vendorId=" + vendorId + "&runYearMonthDate=" + runYearMonthDate));
          //form.attr("action", actionString);
          //form[0].submit();
          return true;
        }
      }
    });

  $myDialog.dialog("open");
}

confirmCancelReadyToRun("thing", "1000020", 5, 2016);
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```